issues when import win32gui in spyder ipython console
can't import win32gui which is already pre-installed in spyder pkgs.
i run pip list in ipython console in spyder and get this:
Package                       Version       
----------------------------- --------------
alabaster                     0.7.13        
arrow                         1.3.0         
astroid                       3.1.0         
asttokens                     2.4.1         
attrs                         23.2.0        
autopep8                      2.0.4         
Babel                         2.14.0        
backcall                      0.2.0         
backports.tarfile             1.0.0         
beautifulsoup4                4.12.3        
binaryornot                   0.4.4         
black                         24.3.0        
bleach                        6.1.0         
certifi                       2024.2.2      
cffi                          1.16.0        
chardet                       5.2.0         
charset-normalizer            3.3.2         
click                         8.1.7         
cloudpickle                   3.0.0         
colorama                      0.4.6         
comm                          0.2.2         
contourpy                     1.1.1         
cookiecutter                  2.6.0         
cryptography                  42.0.5        
cycler                        0.12.1        
Cython                        3.0.10        
debugpy                       1.8.1         
decorator                     5.1.1         
defusedxml                    0.7.1         
diff-match-patch              20230430      
dill                          0.3.8         
docstring-to-markdown         0.15          
docutils                      0.20.1        
et-xmlfile                    1.1.0         
executing                     2.0.1         
fastjsonschema                2.19.1        
flake8                        7.0.0         
fonttools                     4.51.0        
idna                          3.6           
imagesize                     1.4.1         
importlib-metadata            7.1.0         
importlib-resources           6.4.0         
inflection                    0.5.1         
ipykernel                     6.29.4        
ipython                       8.12.3        
isort                         5.13.2        
jaraco.classes                3.4.0         
jaraco.context                5.3.0         
jaraco.functools              4.0.0         
jedi                          0.19.1        
jellyfish                     1.0.3         
Jinja2                        3.1.3         
jsonschema                    4.21.1        
jsonschema-specifications     2023.12.1     
jupyter-client                8.6.1         
jupyter-core                  5.7.2         
jupyterlab-pygments           0.3.0         
keyring                       25.1.0        
kiwisolver                    1.4.5         
markdown-it-py                3.0.0         
MarkupSafe                    2.1.5         
matplotlib                    3.7.5         
matplotlib-inline             0.1.6         
mccabe                        0.7.0         
mdurl                         0.1.2         
mistune                       3.0.2         
more-itertools                10.2.0        
mpmath                        1.3.0         
mypy-extensions               1.0.0         
nbclient                      0.10.0        
nbconvert                     7.16.3        
nbformat                      5.10.4        
nest-asyncio                  1.6.0         
numpy                         1.24.4        
numpydoc                      1.7.0         
openpyxl                      3.1.2         
packaging                     24.0          
pandas                        2.0.3         
pandocfilters                 1.5.1         
paramiko                      3.4.0         
parso                         0.8.4         
pathspec                      0.12.1        
pexpect                       4.9.0         
pickleshare                   0.7.5         
pillow                        10.3.0        
pip                           19.1.1        
pkgutil-resolve-name          1.3.10        
platformdirs                  4.2.0         
pluggy                        1.4.0         
prompt-toolkit                3.0.43        
ptyprocess                    0.7.0         
pure-eval                     0.2.2         
pycodestyle                   2.11.1        
pycparser                     2.22          
pydocstyle                    6.3.0         
pyflakes                      3.2.0         
pygments                      2.17.2        
pylint                        3.1.0         
pylint-venv                   3.0.3         
pyls-spyder                   0.4.0         
pyparsing                     3.1.2         
PyQt5                         5.15.10       
PyQt5-Qt5                     5.15.2        
PyQt5-sip                     12.13.0       
PyQtWebEngine                 5.15.6        
PyQtWebEngine-Qt5             5.15.2        
python-dateutil               2.9.0.post0   
python-lsp-black              2.0.0         
python-lsp-jsonrpc            1.1.2         
python-lsp-server             1.11.0        
pytoolconfig                  1.3.1         
pytz                          2024.1        
pywin32                       306           
pywin32-ctypes                0.2.2         
pyxdg                         0.28          
PyYAML                        6.0.1         
pyzmq                         25.1.2        
QDarkStyle                    3.2.3         
qstylizer                     0.2.2         
QtAwesome                     1.3.1         
qtconsole                     5.5.1         
QtPy                          2.4.1         
referencing                   0.34.0        
requests                      2.31.0        
rich                          13.7.1        
rope                          1.13.0        
rpds-py                       0.18.0        
scipy                         1.10.1        
setuptools                    69.2.0        
six                           1.16.0        
snowballstemmer               2.2.0         
sortedcontainers              2.4.0         
soupsieve                     2.5           
sphinx                        7.1.2         
sphinxcontrib-applehelp       1.0.4         
sphinxcontrib-devhelp         1.0.2         
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp        2.0.1         
sphinxcontrib-jsmath          1.0.1         
sphinxcontrib-qthelp          1.0.3         
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5         
spyder                        5.5.4         
spyder-kernels                2.5.1         
stack-data                    0.6.3         
sympy                         1.12          
tabulate                      0.9.0         
text-unidecode                1.3           
textdistance                  4.6.1         
three-merge                   0.1.1         
tinycss2                      1.2.1         
tomli                         2.0.1         
tomlkit                       0.12.4        
tornado                       6.4           
traitlets                     5.14.2        
types-python-dateutil         2.9.0.20240316
typing-extensions             4.11.0        
tzdata                        2024.1        
ujson                         5.9.0         
urllib3                       2.2.1         
watchdog                      4.0.0         
wcwidth                       0.2.13        
webencodings                  0.5.1         
whatthepatch                  1.0.5         
wheel                         0.43.0        
yapf                          0.40.2        
zipp                          3.18.1  

See pywin32 306 was pre-installed in spyder. Then import win32gui in ipython console and get:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32gui'

pip show pywin32in ipython console and get:
Name: pywin32
Version: 306
Summary: Python for Window Extensions
Home-page: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32
Author: Mark Hammond (et al)
Author-email: mhammond@skippinet.com.au
License: PSF
Location: f:\spyder\pkgs
Requires: 
Required-by: jupyter-core
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

I only installed spyder in my win10 system and no other python version being installed.How can I do with this problem?Thx in advance.
